# CROSS origin issue on angular 7 application

Tags: angular, http, https, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I have working on angular 7 applications and implement rest API calling using httpClient. API works sometime perfectly and sometimes coming below error with status 403:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'API URL' from origin 'API server' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Once this error coming in any of one API after that every API stop the working.

For this applications backend server doe in JAVA. In java, added below code for cross origin allow to access from frontend.

````
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(CorsConfiguration.ALL));
        config.setMaxAge(3600L);
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }```

Please help me out for this.
````

Comment: how you can pass header details to server API in angular web app?

Comment: Which server are you using? Because there are some CORS header settings that can done on the server.

Comment: I have pass header with accept and authorisation token to access the data from backend server.

Comment: I have used AWS server for both angular as well as API.

Comment: in which technology you have implemented backend rest api

Comment: For backend rest API used JAVA spring.

Answer (score 0):

I will give 2 solutions try for that.

1) You can use this annotation **@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")** in your controller class it will allow all the request calls made from the angular applications.

2) Or else you can use this command in your CMD it will disable the **web-security** flag in chrome and it will open new instance of chrome in that just run your angular application so you will never get any CORS errors.This is for Testing purposes.

Command: **chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=c:\my-chrome-data\data**

Answer (score 0):

Please try bellow code will resolve your issue

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Methods, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```